# How can I pass current logged in user while form submission in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.2

I am trying to create a form that allows current logged in user to submit data. 
The form comprises of the field - amount, rate(interest), timestamp(automatically picked up), and currently logged in user.

Data is not passing into the database and giving an error like - The view investors.views.InvestView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

views.py

```
def InvestView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        investment_form = InvestorsForm(request.user)
        context = {'investment_form': investment_form}
        return render(request, 'investors/form.html', context)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        investment_form = InvestorsForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
        if investment_form.is_valid():
            amount = investment_form.cleaned_data['amount']
            interest = investment_form.cleaned_data['rate']
            saving = investment_form.save(commit=False)

            # Passing Logged in user
            investor = request.user
            print(investor)
            saving.investor = request.user.id
            saving.save()
            messages.success(request, f'New Investment Done!')
            return redirect('/myinvest/')
```

forms.py

```
class InvestorsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta :
        model = Investment
        fields = ['amount', 'rate']

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(InvestorsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

models.py

```
class Investor(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=99) 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Investment(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    rate = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    timestamp = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    investor = models.ForeignKey(Investor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.investor)
```

Data must be stored into the database and redirect the page to myinvest section simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another error: your form's `__init__` method takes a `user` as its first argument:

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
```

In the case of a GET request, you pass it correctly:

```
investment_form = InvestorsForm(request.user)
```

But then with a POST request, you forget it:

```
investment_form = InvestorsForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
```

Passing request.user as the first argument there as well should help.

Comment: I have added this line - investment_form = InvestorsForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user) in the views.py

Comment: @ManishGupta: So that still has the problem that I explain in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has nothing to do with adding the user. It is because you do nothing in case the validation fails.

You should turn your function the other way round so that the render is hit in all cases.

```
def InvestView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        investment_form = InvestorsForm(request.POST)
        if investment_form.is_valid():
            saving = investment_form.save(commit=False)
            saving.investor.user = request.user
            saving.save()
            messages.success(request, f'New Investment Done!')
            return redirect('/myinvest/')
    else:
        investment_form = InvestorsForm()
    context = {'investment_form': investment_form}
    return render(request, 'investors/form.html', context)
```

Note the indentation.

The actual failure to validate is because you have changed the signature of the form to accept a `user` parameter first, instead of the expected `data`. However it is not clear why you have done this as you do not use that value, but instead set the user in the view. You should **remove** that `__init__` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `saving.investor = request.user.id` with `saving.investor.user = request.user`.

Comment: same issues. Please check forms.py or models.py if you find any bug there. I am not able to recognize. You can suggest any other method